# Chrome Extension - Show div only on Load up

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble with a chrome extension. When you click the icon in your browser, it loads the extension. That's normal. But what if you want to have your logo in there first?

Like the apps on iOS devices have: show the logo first, then load the app.

So I have the div `<div class="loader"></div>` in my `popup.html`. This div makes the screen all white with my logo in the middle, after 1 seconds it fades away and shows the content.

But now: Is it possible to show the `<div class="loader"></div>` only when it loads up instead of it always showing when you load `popup.html`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here when you say "only when it loads up instead of it always showing when you load popup.html". My guess is that you mean, only show the popup when you first click it within a session and not on subsequent clicks.

If so, you may be able to rig something up to disable other browser actions after the initial load in your popup.html. That's in this API [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-enable), but my feeling is that this is not yet easily possible without then writing your own code to manage all actions.

Comment: @eholder0 First off, thanks for your comment, I thought nobody would comment and leave this in the dust. I'm trying to have a `div` show when they click the top right extension button. Then when the visitor goes to the about page for example in the extension and returns to the index page, the `div`  won't show anymore. The `div` can only show when the extension loads up, not when the visitor already loaded the extension and just returned from an page. I hope you understand, english isnt my native language and I find it hard to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood correctly you can do:

in your background page:

```
localStorage['onLoadingFirstTime'] = 'true';
```

So every time you start the browser a variable is stored in the localstorage with a value  of 'true'.  This means your first time.

After in the popup.js you can write something like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    if (localStorage['onLoadingFirstTime'] == 'true') {
        document.getElementsByClassName('loader')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
        localStorage['onLoadingFirstTime'] = 'false';
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('loader')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
});
```

So in the popup.js when it's completely laded you can check the value of the variable stored in the localstorage:

if yes (means first time) you set this value to false and show your div.

if not (means second or more times you clicked on the extension) you hide the div.

I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: This would probably work, but I would modify it slightly to be if the value is false or not found (not sure if that comes up as null or undefined, but could check both honestly), then consider that the first load and set the value to true. From there on, if true then do nothing. Doing it this way also alleviates having to set anything in your background script, so you can contain this entirely to the logic in popup.js/html.